# Get Perforce Credentials with .NET

Tags: .net, perforce

Lots of times when I use an application that needs perforce access (Visual Studio, Unreal Editor) when I first use it, it will pop up a dialog where the user can enter their information (user, workspace, etc). Does anyone know of a way to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably seeing is the login dialog from the Perforce SCC plugin. There is a standard API for IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio) to communicate with source control systems, but I believe you have to sign an NDA with (or at least pay a fee to) Microsoft in order to program against it.

[what in general does the SCC API do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566639/what-in-general-does-the-scc-api-do)

Answer (score 0):

[P4COM](http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/p4com/main/) and [P4.Net](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4.net) are APIs that allow you to interface to Perforce with .NET languages (among others).

Comment: neither of those offers this feature

Comment: @Jared: perhaps I misunderstood your question.  I took it to mean you would like to write an app in .NET that can interact with Perforce.  Could you edit your question and describe in more detail exactly what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Perforce stores client side settings such as user, server:port, client etc in environment variables i.e P4USER, P4PORT, P4CLIENT.
On Windows, these variables are stored in the registry ( though if you ran on Windows under say Cygwin they will be stored and read as environment variables ).

You can view these variables using the perforce command `p4 set` - this will display all variables currently set on this machine.

For more info about all perforce variable then read [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/_env.html#1045283)

Whether you call `p4.exe` directly through .NET by using `System.Diagnostics.Process` or whether you use one of the available libraries such as `P4.NET` or `P4COM` then any commands you run will use these settings as default.

If you want to override these default settings by popping up a dialog box in .NET then you'll need to code this yourself.

As an example using [P4COM](http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/p4com/main/index.html) then you'd do the following:
1) Create your own dialog to get the info you want such user, client etc
2) Create a p4 instance i.e `P4COM.p4 myp4 = new P4COM.p4();`
3) Set the connection parameters you want i.e `myP4.User = 'UserVal'`
4) Call p4.connect i.e `myp4.Connect();`

Note that in P4COM, the various properties on a newly created p4 instance class will contain the current defaults for user, port etc so you could also read these first then present them in a dialog box to the user for them to change if needed.